# Spring Integration Java DSL Error

Tags: spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have set up a new Spring Boot + Spring Integration + Spring Integration Java DSL project using latest available versions. The project builds okay but, when I run the application, I am getting:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.integration.dsl.StandardIntegrationFlow.isRegisterComponents()Z
    at org.springframework.integration.dsl.config.IntegrationFlowBeanPostProcessor.processStandardIntegrationFlow(IntegrationFlowBeanPostProcessor.java:139) ~[spring-integration-java-dsl-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.integration.dsl.config.IntegrationFlowBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(IntegrationFlowBeanPostProcessor.java:100) ~[spring-integration-java-dsl-1.2.3.RELEASE.jar:?]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:423) ~[spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1702) ~[spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:583) ~[spring-beans-5.0.3.RELEASE.jar:5.0.3.RELEASE]
```

The dependencies being used are currently as follows:

```
compile ("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.0.0.RC1") {
    exclude group: "org.springframework.boot", module: "spring-boot-starter-logging"
}
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.0.0.RC1"
compile "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-log4j2:2.0.0.RC1"
compile "org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-core:5.0.1.RELEASE"
compile "org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-http:5.0.1.RELEASE"
compile "org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-jms:5.0.1.RELEASE"
compile "org.springframework.integration:spring-integration-java-dsl:1.2.3.RELEASE"
```

Could the error be due to wrong combination of jar versions? I am not sure how to debug this error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use Spring Integration `5.0` already, you don't need that extra `spring-integration-java-dsl` dependency. It has been merged to the core project since the version `5.0`.

See more info in the [Migration Guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/wiki/Spring-Integration-4.3-to-5.0-Migration-Guide) and on that page for [Spring Integration Java DSL](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-java-dsl/wiki/Spring-Integration-Java-DSL-Reference) project.